# Handling QMetaType registration in Qt5 with dynamic plug-ins

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcore, qmetatype

My company is considering the jump from Qt 4.8.4 to Qt 5.4, but I came across a change that could be a showstopper for us: `QMetaType::unregisterType()` is removed (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html).

Our GUI requires plug-ins to be loaded at runtime, with the same plug-in potentially loaded and unloaded more than once during a session of the GUI. In Qt 4, we ran into an issue where when the plug-in was loaded the second time, any signal/slot that used one of the custom types registered by the plug-in would cause access violations because the meta type had been registered by the first instance of the plug-in (which was now unloaded, so the memory space was invalid). We worked around this issue by defining our own macros to register and unregister meta types safely as the plug-in was loaded and unloaded.

With `QMetaType::unregisterType()` no longer present, I fear that this issue will come back with no real way to solve the problem. Upgrading to Qt 5.4 would be a significant investment to even get to the point that I could test this issue, so I'm hoping I can get some indication from the experts here.

Is there any way to unregister a meta type in Qt 5? If not, does Qt 5 now have some sort of system that can detect when the DLL is being unloaded and unregister the meta types itself (highly unlikely I'd assume)? Alternatively, if we switch to the new Qt 5 signal/slot syntax, does that absolve us of the need for meta types entirely? If so, does the new syntax still allow for queued connections? Please forgive my ignorance on the subject, but I don't see it explicitly listed as supported or not.

Comment: [This is related.](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/odysseus-qtbase/commit/b8cf1d6bdcaefaa610014a742808af3ab2c6fe06)

Comment: You still need the meta types for queued connections.

Comment: @lpapp Well that's unfortunate and rather short-sighted... A significant portion of the need for plug-ins is the need to dynamically load and unload things that you don't want or can't have in your main application, but I guess the Qt folks think differently.

Oktalist: Do you have a link or anything that states this as fact? I believe you, but I'd like something I can send up the chain so that management understands the issue.

Comment: @iamtheddrman: usually you load plugins on startup, not load and unload during the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please forgive my ignorance on the subject, but I don't see it explicitly listed as supported or not.

This is currently unsupported, which means that do not unload plugins with Qt 5 as of writing this. Usually, you do not load and unload plugins anyway, as it is done during the launch up in general. The [corresponding change](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/15155/) in the repository also claims:

> The function hasn't been working properly. It was not well tested, for example it is undefined how QVariant should behave if it contains an instance of an unregistered type.
>
> Concept of unregistering types was inspired by plug-in system, but in most supported platforms we do not unload plug-ins.
>
> Idea of type unregistering may block optimizations in meta object system, because it would be not possible to cache a type id. QMetaType::type() could return different ids for the same name.

Thereby, even though you thought it was working, it was unreliable which means you could have observed difficult to find bugs in its operation, resulting unreliable software on your part. I am sure you do not want to release such a software, especially if it is not recommended by the Qt Project to be used.

Comment: Thank you for the response. You are correct in saying that the typical use is at startup and never unload, but that is not the ONLY use of plug-ins. Our plug-in architecture doesn't lend itself to this type of behavior, so this will require some real work to change. So much work, in fact, that we may have to just not upgrade to Qt 5 because it would be prohibitively expensive to do so. At least I have the information I need now!

Comment: @iamtheddrman: I think you did not get the message. I will try to clarify: do not rely on broken and unreliable thing even in Qt 4. Just because it currently seems to work, it does not mean it will not blow up at any moment. If you want such a feature, implement that yourself. Qt is currently not the right place for it.

Comment: I got the point. We're going to explore a way to keep our plug-ins loaded even with Qt 4. It's not top priority because we've been using like this for years and have not had any observed issues to date. Sidenote: it's annoying when developers say "this hasn't been working properly", but only give one example which I would interpret as being abuse of the system anyway (we won't have any QVariants loaded with a type we're trying to unregister because that doesn't seem like it would ever work). In lieu of examples of bad behavior, we'll continue to use it until we have budget to fix it...

Comment: @iamtheddrman: not sure what is annoying about not supporting unreliable features.I do not think it is abuse, just undhandled case that you would need to explicitly care about. It is not good. Furthermore, optimization is also important in the core, so degrading the performance in the core for corner cases sounds like counter-productive to me. Also, this is not used anywhere inside Qt either, so they felt it better for Qt 5 to remove and maybe add it later once the concept and ideas get stable. You know, it is simpler to add features to a binary compatible library than removing ...

Comment: It's the lack of explanation that's annoying. "Not working properly" could mean just about anything. There are other cases where Qt is fine with odd or undefined behavior as well, so I already have to be careful. Qt's excellent documentation typically outlines these scenarios well so that we can deal with them. You do have a point about the optimization though. Qt is pretty quick for what it does, so I can understand the desire to keep that up. Thanks for the dialogue, as that's always nice to have with issues like this.